# Change Hyper-V HNSNetwork Subnet Mask

Tags: hyper-v, nat

I'm on Windows 10 Pro Build 1803, and my default Hyper-V HNSNetwork is assigning IPs to my virtual machines correctly. However, the IPs are seemingly leased for some time, even if the VMs are turned off and unregistered. If multiple different machines are imported/exported, my network runs out of IPs to lease, and the VMs get a non-routable IP until I restart Windows.

I have found that `Get-HnsNetwork` returns `Subnets: {@{AddressPrefix=172.18.254.96/28; GatewayAddress=172.18.254.97}}`

Clearly, the `/28` mask is limiting my network to very few IPs for my use case (15?) and I'd like to change it to `/24`.

What is the correct way to do this? I cannot find any current documentation on the matter.

EDIT: I am aware I can create a new virtual switch and use that. I'm interested in whether the settings for the default switch can be changed.

Alternatively, is there a way to "reset" the service that leases the IPs? Is there a DHCP server that can be reset without rebooting?

Comment: Who leases your IPs ? At /28 you have 14 available IPs. If you make it a /24 you will have 254 IPs to work with.

Comment: Some service, that's exactly the question. If I knew what service is leasing them I would just restart it. I thought there'd be something called like HNSNetwork service but I can't find such a thing in my services list.

Comment: If you don't administer that I strongly doubt you can change any class/range settings.